How to display a thumbnail image of my quarto website when I share its url
I have a quarto website and everytime I share its home url or any blog post url, the shared link in WhatsApp or any other messaging system doesn't display any image.
How do I configure this to be a custom image?
I think I need to modify some meta tag, but I don't know how to do that in quarto either.


You would need Open Graph for this:
website:
  title: "Your Website"
  image: "image.png"  
  open-graph: true

